# Como cambiar el formato a una cadena tipo DateTime con CultureInfo

Tags: c#

intento cambiar el formato de un DateTime.Now a español,pero no se como aplicarle el CultureInfo a la cadena, he estado investigando pero no he dado con una solucion para mi caso. Es una cadena que invoco en el Load de un formulario y se lo paso a un Label.

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");

lblfecha.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
```

Alguien sabe como cambiar la cadena de ingles a español?

Gracias de antemano,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToLongDateString()` es equivalente a hacer `ToString("D")` (D es formato largo), y puesto que `ToString()` si admite un proveedor de formato, podrías hacer algo así:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
lblfecha.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("D", culture);
```

Answer (score 1):

El metodo ToLongDateString no recibe un parametro, pero podes resolverlo asi. Seteando la clase CultureInfo le cambias directamente al hilo del programa tu configuracion predeterminada y no tenes que estar configurando cada `.ToString();`

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");

  string fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString();
  string fecha2 = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
```